# Copy and paste in Excel VBA with variable range

Tags: excel, vba, variables, copy, range

```
For day = 1 To days
    copyToCol = day * 2
    dataFile.Worksheets(day).Activate
    Set found = dataFile.Worksheets(day).Range("A2:Z5").Find(subStation).Offset(2, 0)
   
     With dataFile.Worksheets(day)
         'The next two lines give me errors
         .Range(.Cells(found.Row, found.Column), .Cells(found.Offset(23, 0).Row, found.Column)).Copy _
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(subStation).Range(Cells(1, copyToCol), Cells(24, copyToCol))
     End With
    
Next day
```

This question might seem noob... but I give up. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: You need to qualify the `Cells` calls, see the linked question.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your question - what is not working? What have you tried to make it work?